# Render problem with RecyclerView android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, rendering

I'm having an issue with recyclerview in android studio. When I add it to my constraint layout it says Android...RecyclerView and I cant add anything to it. This is [what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgy7i.jpg) and [this is my layout tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74afy.jpg). I have searched all of stackoverflow and I cannot find ANYTHING. Please help. This is my `activity_main` xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#505050"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/messageInput"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Type a message..."
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sendButton"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="Send"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/messageInput" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/messageView"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="487dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#56565"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/messageInput"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean "You cannot add anything to it"?  You don't put things in a recyclerview, you set an adapter to it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File>Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Gradle and uncheck the Offline Work.

Sync and Build.

If the problem still persists try changing the API version of the rendering engine and select other theme of the app. See Image below

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Why I have no theme in tool-bar?

Comment: click first one of your layout xml file then go to Design tab where you drag and drop, you should see this.

Comment: If still does not work, try changing android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView to android.support.v4.widget.RecyclerView, then sync and build.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i wonder why I do not have many kinds of buttons in Activity xml but have them in content xml?And it didn’t show the component like plain text in blue print even if i dragged that to inside.

Comment: Try different API. example 17,19,23. Also try other theme like Holo.Light. Also try checking your manifest.xml and gradle.script.

Comment: @pajarnas did the problem solved? you can mark my post as answer :) good luck to your app.

Comment: sorry i can’t, i am not the guy who ask the question but i upvoted thanks